# Get MIN, MAX, AVG value with datetime for each DAY (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, max, average, min

I have a MySQL database with lots of entrys with columns like "local_time", "temp", "wind", etc.

What I want to archive is get in just one query the MIN value for temp, the MAX value for temp in each day with the datetime for min and max.

eg:

```
local_time | temp

2022-12-01 12:20 | 10
2022-12-01 12:40 |20

2022-12-02 19:00 | 12
2022-12-02 20:05 | 8

2022-12-03 22:22 | 14
2022-12-03 22:30 | 16
```

Result I wanted for query:

```
date | min | min_date | max | max_date| avg

2022-12-01 | 10 | datetime | 20 | datetime | avg_value
2022-12-02 | 8 | datetime | 12 | datetime | avg_value
2022-12-03 | 14 | datetime | 16 | datetime | avg_value
```

For now, I'm using this query:

`select DATE(local_time) as local_time, MIN(temp) as max, MAX(temp) as min, AVG(temp) as avg FROM data GROUP BY DATE(local_time);`

But I need the datetime (local_time) for the MIN value and MAX value, for every single day.

Any help is welcome.

For now, I'm using this query:

`select DATE(local_time) as local_time, MIN(temp) as max, MAX(temp) as min, AVG(temp) as avg FROM data GROUP BY DATE(local_time);`

But I need the datetime (local_time) for the MIN value and MAX value, for every single day.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: thta makes no sense, how can the date of min value of that day be different fom the day you get the minvalue, so show the excat date you want to show

Comment: @Mureinik MySQL

Comment: @nbk maybe the date column is not needed as the min_date and max_date per row is the same DATE but diferent DATETIME.

Comment: You should put the right datetime and avg values in the excpected result to make it clearer

Comment: `MIN(temp) as max, MAX(temp) as min` is a tad misleading I daresay :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I din't get it working in one go so I joined two queries:
a group by query to get your min, max and average and
one using window functions to get mindate for min and maxdate for max:

```
select a.local_date, a.min, b.mindatetime , a.max, b.maxdatetime, a.avg from 
(select DATE(local_time) as local_date, 
        MIN(temp) as min,  
        MAX(temp) as max, AVG(temp) as avg
   FROM data GROUP BY DATE(local_time)) a
join 
(select distinct DATE(local_time) as local_date, 
                 first_value(local_time) OVER ( PARTITION BY DATE(local_time) order by temp asc) as mindatetime,
                 first_value(local_time) OVER ( PARTITION BY DATE(local_time) order by temp desc) as maxdatetime
  from data) b on a.local_date = b.local_date
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/owZiLJuKhqc4DF6XYa3aJV/0

I guess the query with window functions leaves space for optimizing...

**EDIT**

Just wondered if a version only with window functions would perform better(It's nicer to look at anyway):

```
select distinct DATE(local_time) as local_date, 
 MIN(temp) OVER ( PARTITION BY DATE(local_time) )  as min,
first_value(local_time) OVER ( PARTITION BY DATE(local_time) order by temp asc) as mindatetime,
 MAX(temp) OVER ( PARTITION BY DATE(local_time) )  as max,
first_value(local_time) OVER ( PARTITION BY DATE(local_time) order by temp desc) as maxdatetime,
 AVG(temp) OVER ( PARTITION BY DATE(local_time) )  as avg
from data
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/owZiLJuKhqc4DF6XYa3aJV/2

Comment: Hi Turo, your solution seems to be doing what a I want. It takes 0.23 seconds to do the work with around 50k rows in the table 'data'. Your solution seems good. I don't know if theres a space for optimization of the query.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you multiple identical Min values or MAX values for that matter, you need to adjust the subqueries

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  local_time datetime,
  temp INT
,INDEX(local_time)
);
INSERT INTO data  VALUES ('2022-12-01 12:20' , 10);
INSERT INTO data  VALUES ('2022-12-01 12:40' ,20);

INSERT INTO data  VALUES ('2022-12-02 19:00' , 12);
INSERT INTO data  VALUES ('2022-12-02 20:05' , 8);

INSERT INTO data  VALUES ('2022-12-03 22:22' , 14);
INSERT INTO data  VALUES ('2022-12-03 22:30' , 16);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    DATE(d.local_time) AS local_time,
    MAX(d.temp) AS max,
    MAX((SELECT local_time FROM data WHERE DATE(local_time) = DATE(d.local_time) ORDEr BY temp DESC LIMIT 1)) max_datetime,
    MIN(d.temp) AS min,
    MIN((SELECT local_time FROM data WHERE DATE(local_time) = DATE(d.local_time) ORDEr BY temp ASC LIMIT 1)) min_datetime,
    AVG(d.temp) AS avg
FROM
    data d
  GROUP BY DATE(d.local_time);
```

| local_time | max | max_datetime | min | min_datetime | avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-01 | 20 | 2022-12-01 12:40:00 | 10 | 2022-12-01 12:20:00 | 15.0000 |
| 2022-12-02 | 12 | 2022-12-02 19:00:00 | 8 | 2022-12-02 20:05:00 | 10.0000 |
| 2022-12-03 | 16 | 2022-12-03 22:30:00 | 14 | 2022-12-03 22:22:00 | 15.0000 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/owZiLJuKhqc4DF6XYa3aJV/1)

Comment: Ah! the limit 1 in the subquery is the idea I was missing!

Comment: Looks like you used my db-fidle and forgot to save before sharing :-)

Comment: @nbk thank you, but your solution for an unknown reason takes lot of time but not complete the task.

Comment: @cbn you table has no index add one for the local time will help with the performance, you can test it , with  a combined index for temp and localtime also

Comment: @Turo i updated my answer with the correct link

Comment: @nbk I will try to create an index for local_time and I will check how perform your query. Thank you friend.

Comment: @nbk: Even set local_time as Primary Key, it takes so much time... if remove the MIN and MAX of the SELECT it takes 3 seconds... too much time.

Comment: it should be that slow, with a fast server, may try to reduce the data that are exaxmined, further see in the mysql error log if there are any hint,

Comment: @cbn if you like to experiment you could try to replace `DATE(local_time) = DATE(d.local_time)` with something like `local_time between DATE(d.local_time) AND DATE_ADD(DATE(d.local_time) , INTERVAL 1 DAY)`, maybe then mysql is willing to make better use of the index...

Comment: @Turo no mysql uses where because it returns the two rows and so will always be fatser than an index

Answer (score 0):

You say you want the time for the minimum temperature and the time for the maximum temperature per day, but rather than using singular you should use the plural. Yes, there is one minimum and maximum temperature per day, but there is not necessarily *one* time when that minimum resp. that maximum temperature is reached. These temperatures can occur multiple times a day. We must first determine a rule what to do in case of such ties, then find the algorithm.

Let's say we are looking for the first time the minimum was reached and the last time the maximum was reached. (We could look at well vice versa or collect all times one of the temperatures is met.)

We need two steps: First, find the minimum and maximum temperatures per day, then aggregate the data to get one row per day.

```
select
  local_date,
  min(temp) as min_temp,
  min(case when temp = min_temp then local_time end) as first_min_temp_time,
  max(temp) as max_temp,
  max(case when temp = max_temp then local_time end) as last_max_temp_time,
  avg(temp) as avg_temp
from
(
  select
    date(local_time) as local_date,
    time(local_time) as local_time,
    temp,
    min(temp) over (partition by date(local_time)) as min_temp,
    max(temp) over (partition by date(local_time)) as max_temp
  from data
) temperatures
group by local_date
order by local_date;
```

Well, if you were looking for the *first* time the maximum temperature is reached, that would be

```
min(case when temp = max_temp then local_time end) as first_max_temp_time,
```

of course, and if you were looking for all the times that temperature occured in the day, it would be something along the lines of

```
group_concat(case when temp = max_temp then time_format(local_time, '%H:%i') end
             order by local_time
             separator ', '
            ) as all_max_temp_times,
```